# How to connect spotify auth in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, spotify, flutter-dependencies

i am using spotify_sdk 1.0.1 plugin to spotify auth in my flutter app. I have setup everything its also working perfectly when it is in debug mode but not in release mode.

please help me.

pubspec.yaml-> adding package

flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.5
url_launcher: ^5.7.10
spotify_sdk: ^1.0.1

```
 Future<void> connectToSpotifyRemote() async {
try {
  setState(() {
    _loading = true;
  });
  var result = await SpotifySdk.connectToSpotifyRemote(
    clientId: clientId,
    redirectUrl: redirectUrl,);
  setStatus(result
      ? 'connect to spotify successful'
      : 'connect to spotify failed');
  setState(() {
    _loading = false;
  });
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  setState(() {
    _loading = false;
  });
  setStatus(e.code, message: e.message);

} on MissingPluginException {

  setState(() {
    _loading = false;
  });
  setStatus('not implemented');

}
```

}

Future getAuthenticationToken() async {
try {

```
  var authenticationToken = await SpotifySdk.getAuthenticationToken(
      clientId: clientId,
      redirectUrl: redirectUrl,
      scope: 'app-remote-control, '
          'user-modify-playback-state, '
          'playlist-read-private, '
          'playlist-modify-public,user-read-currently-playing');
  setStatus('Got a token: $authenticationToken');
  return authenticationToken;

 } on PlatformException catch (e) {

   setStatus(e.code, message: e.message);
   return Future.error('$e.code: $e.message');

 } on MissingPluginException {

   setStatus('not implemented');
   return Future.error('not implemented');

 }
```

}

void setStatus(String code, {String message = ''}) {

```
var text = message.isEmpty ? '' : ' : $message';
_logger.d('$code$text');
```

}

also added packages in android module

spotify-auth
spotify-app-remote

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: Hi brother, did you manage to setup `spotify_sdk` for Android successfully?

Comment: I'm got stuck since 4 days. I need your help just for the setup `spotify_sdk`. Pls send msg/call on 0304-4819330. 
I shall be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

ensure you added internet permission in your android manifest folder

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```